# How to access custom data from a customer session in JS file?

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs, customer-session

Is there any way to access custom data stored in a customer session from a **JS file** ( **without Ajax call** ).

Here is the code for controller:

```
<?php

namespace Company\Vendor\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Session;

class Index extends Action
{
    protected $_customerSession;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Session $customerSession
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $this->_customerSession->setMyValue('yes');
    }
}
```

To access the MyValue value, we can use `$this->_customerSession->getMyValue();`

How can I get the MyValue value in a JS file?

Answer (score 0):

[Not sure it's the correct way or best way] We need to set **uncacheable page** (will **impact the performance**). This is because when enabling the full page cache, the customer session will be clear.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but as you said it will impact the performance :|